# How to create selection from DOM element itself

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js, if I'm given a CSS selector that uniquely identifies a DOM element, I can create a selection containing only that element, using, for example,

```
svg.selectAll("g.node#"+d.id)
```

Suppose that I'm given the DOM element itself, for example, a particular `<g>` that already exists.  Passing the DOM element directly to `selectAll` or `select` generates an error, reported as "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified" in Firefox, or "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[object SVGGElement]' is not a valid selector" in Chrome.

How can I create a selection from the reference to DOM element itself?  There should be no need to cause D3 to go and search for the element using a CSS selector.

At the moment, I've got working code that gets the appropriate selection by constructing a unique CSS selector, but that seems like unnecessary work, since I already have a reference to the DOM element to which I want to append things.

EDIT:

Thanks to @meetamit and @LarsKotthoff: OK, if it should just work to `selectAll` on the DOM element, there's something I don't understand about my code (not surprising).  I was trying to avoid dumping a lot of code into my SO question, but I don't know what else to do.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mars0i/zfwnfxg8/2/).  It doesn't run in jsfiddle, and I don't know why, but it runs just fine without jsfiddle in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  (Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mars0i/8k178my6/1/) that just contains my entire file in the HTML window.)

My code is supposed to add a little pack layout to each node in a force layout.  There may be a purely idiomatic way to do this, but I've only succeded in getting it to work by calling `each` on the nodes in the force layout, adding the pack layouts from inside a separate function:

```
var svgnodes = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(data.nodes, function (d) {return d.id;})
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", function (d) {return d.id;})
    .call(layout.drag())
    .on("click", click);

svgnodes.each(function (d, i) {addPersonCircles(d, svg, this);});
```

Here's part of the definition of `addPersonCircles`:

```
function addPersonCircles (d, svg, personG) {
    // makes a data new structure for use by pack layout:
    function makeroot (id) {return {"name":name, "children":[{"name":"a"}, {"name":"p"}]};}

      // data structure containing three elements, one for each element generated by makeroot()
    var pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .size([personRadius, personRadius])
        .value(function (d) {return 1;})
        .nodes(makeroot(d.id));

    // KLUDGE. Isn't there a way to select using the dom element personG that was passed in?
    svg.selectAll("g.node#"+d.id)    // find particular existing g node in person net
        .selectAll("circle.person")  // create new circles within g node
        .data(pack)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        ...
}
```

When I add `console.log(personG)`, i.e. display what was `this` inside of `each()`, what's displayed is something like this:

```
<g class="node" id="sandra" transform="translate(263.59494561798255,242.1803122208288)">...</g>
```

I have been puzzled at times by what `this` refers to, but here it seems to refer to a DOM node, and nothing else.  However when I replace `svg.selectAll("g.node#"+d.id)` with `svg.selectAll(personG)`, I get the error messages reported above.  The result looks like the following.  Thanks for any help.

[image: 4 circles with links, each containing two circles]

Comment: svg.selectAll('g'). or for example svg.selectAll('rect')

Comment: That's using a CSS selector, @agconti.  I already know how to do that.

Comment: Given a dom element `el` you can call `d3.select(el)` and get a valid selection. If that doesn't work then something else is wrong, like maybe `el` is not actually a DOM element but another d3 selection or a jQuery selector or something else.

Comment: From the error message it sounds like you're trying to use an array of several elements instead of a single element.

Comment: @Mars thats referencing the DOM elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn a DOM node into a D3 selection using `d3.select()`. You *cannot* turn a DOM node into a D3 selection using `selection.selectAll()`. The code you want is

```
d3.select(personG) 
    .selectAll("circle.person")  // create new circles within g node
    // ...
```

Note two important points:

1. The root of the statement is the global `d3.` not the selection `svg.`
2. The selection is made using `select()` not `selectAll()`

Meetamit has it exactly correct.

Comment: Excellent.  That works.  Thank you for the explanation.  And yes, I misunderstood that @meetamit meant that I had to use exactly that form.  (Why that method and only that one works, and not the other options listed in your answer, and why in other contexts when calling `select` on `d3`, I ended up with `g`s outside of my `<svg></svg>` .... I leave those questions to the future when I come to grok the d3 way. :-)

Comment: Here's a good place to start in the [D3.js documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#subselections)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a single DOM node into a D3 selection using [d3.select()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#select):

> If the selector is not a string, instead selects the specified node; this is useful if you already have a reference to a node, such as this within an event listener or a global such as document.body

Further, you can turn an array of DOM node into a d3 selection using [d3.selectAll()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selectAll):

> If the selector is not a string, instead selects the specified array of nodes; this is useful if you already have a reference to nodes, such as this.childNodes ...

Comment: The first point seems to duplicate what @StephenThomas wrote more than two years ago.  The second point contradicts something that he wrote, but doesn't give any explanation about what to do.

Comment: Hi @Mars; its `select()` for a single node and `selectAll()` for an array of nodes. You can't use them interchangeably. Just wanted to make it clear. Cheers.